# npm rebuild --verbose sharp выдаёт ошибку

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Попытался установить IconGenie для Quasar Framework, при запуске icongenie generate выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
PS E:\TestQuasar\test> icongenie generate

E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\@quasar\icongenie\node_modules\sharp\lib\constructor.js:34
  throw new Error(error);
  ^

Error:
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp.node'
Require stack:
- E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\@quasar\icongenie\node_modules\sharp\lib\constructor.js
- E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\@quasar\icongenie\node_modules\sharp\lib\index.js
- E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\@quasar\icongenie\lib\utils\get-files-options.js
- E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\@quasar\icongenie\lib\cmd\generate.js
- E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\@quasar\icongenie\bin\icongenie-generate
- E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\@quasar\icongenie\bin\icongenie

- Run "npm rebuild --verbose sharp" and look for errors
- Consult the installation documentation at https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install
- Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues

    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\@quasar\icongenie\node_modules\sharp\lib\constructor.js:34:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\@quasar\icongenie\node_modules\sharp\lib\index.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
```

Запускаю npm rebuild --verbose sharp и получаю такую кучу ошибок:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\TestQuasar\test\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! info sharp Using existing vendored libvips v8.8.1
npm ERR! info sharp Creating E:\TestQuasar\test\node_modules\sharp\build\Release
npm ERR! info sharp Copying DLLs from E:\TestQuasar\test\node_modules\sharp\vendor\lib to E:\TestQuasar\test\node_modules\sharp\build\Release
npm ERR! prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 5.3.6
npm ERR! prebuild-install info install installing standalone, skipping download.
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'E:\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'E:\\nvm\\v15.5.1\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild'
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.5.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking Python explicitly set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - "--python=" or "npm config get python" is "C:\python27\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\python27\python.exe" to get executable path
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "C:\python27\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\python27\python.exe" to get version
npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "2.7.0"
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.0 found at "C:\python27\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 15.5.1
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '15.5.1' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "15.5.1"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 15.5.1
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 15.5.1
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: E:\TestQuasar\test\node_modules\sharp\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? E:\TestQuasar\test\node_modules\sharp\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1342) found at:
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - missing any Windows SDK
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS checking VS2017 (15.8.28010.2003) found at:
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
npm ERR! gyp verb find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17134.0
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.8.28010.2003) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: E:\TestQuasar\test\node_modules\sharp\build\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: E:\TestQuasar\test\node_modules\sharp\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: E:\TestQuasar\test\node_modules\sharp\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'E:\\nvm\\v15.5.1\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'E:\\TestQuasar\\test\\node_modules\\sharp\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'E:\\nvm\\v15.5.1\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Илья\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\15.5.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Илья\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\15.5.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=E:\\nvm\\v15.5.1\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\Илья\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\15.5.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=E:\\TestQuasar\\test\\node_modules\\sharp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'E:\\TestQuasar\\test\\node_modules\\sharp\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 51, in <module>
npm ERR!   File "E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 670, in script_main
npm ERR!     return main(sys.argv[1:])
npm ERR!   File "E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 662, in main
npm ERR!     return gyp_main(args)
npm ERR!   File "E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 647, in gyp_main
npm ERR!     generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
npm ERR!   File "E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 2140, in GenerateOutput
npm ERR!     _GenerateProject(project, options, msvs_version, generator_flags, spec)
npm ERR!   File "E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1027, in _GenerateProject
npm ERR!     return _GenerateMSBuildProject(project, options, version, generator_flags, spec)
npm ERR!   File "E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 3825, in _GenerateMSBuildProject
npm ERR!     easy_xml.WriteXmlIfChanged(content, project.path, pretty=True, win32=True)
npm ERR!   File "E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\easy_xml.py", line 124, in WriteXmlIfChanged
npm ERR!     xml_string = xml_string.encode(encoding)
npm ERR! UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 2393: ordinal not in range(128)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (E:\nvm\v15.5.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:284:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "E:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\nvm\\v15.5.1\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\TestQuasar\test\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.5.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm verb exit 1
npm timing npm Completed in 8211ms
```

Что мне надо установить, чтобы всё заработало? Помогите, пожалуйста :(

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что у меня имя пользователя содержит латинские символы, сменил категорию node-gyp и всё запустилось успешно.

npm config set --global devdir D:\node-gyp